# How to implement the use of Ids using MVC Front to Back

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Basically this a simple Add,Modify,Delete webpage Im doing in MVC5, with EF6 using Repository Pattern (without Unit Of Work for now) and DI with IoC (Autofac).

This is my domain class using EF 6:

```
public partial class Turnos
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Turnos()
    {
        Alumnos = new HashSet<Alumnos>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Alumnos> Alumnos { get; set; }
}
```

And this `Id` from `Turnos` is been used by another table (1 to n relationship)

```
public partial class Alumnos
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Apellido { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Legajo { get; set; }

    public int Dni { get; set; }

    public int Carrera { get; set; }

    public int Turno { get; set; }

    public virtual Carreras Carreras { get; set; }

    public virtual Turnos Turnos { get; set; }
}
```

These are my models:

```
public class AlumnoModel
{
    #region Fields
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Apellido { get; set; }
    public string Legajo { get; set; }
    public int Dni { get; set; }
    public int Carrera { get; set; }
    public int Turno { get; set; }
    #endregion
}

public class TurnoModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}
```

In my View `Turnos` is a partial view that populate a dropdown list using Razor using:

```
        @{
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <option id="@item.Id">@item.Descripcion</option>
            }
        }
```

Now my questions are:
Is it safe to send my unique `Id`s to the front when Inserting? And if not
What is the best way to send the `Id` of the element that the person selected? comparing strings is out of the question of course.

And If it is safe to send my `Id`s when Im inserting an `Alumno`, how can I protect myself of someone changing the order of the `Id`s using the developers console?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be safe for users to see the IDs?  Also, you can't prevent users from modifying client-side values.  But, again, what exactly would this accomplish for the user?  What are you concerned would happen?

Comment: What I can do is validate if the Id Selected is out of bounds, Imagine this Dropdown:
1 - Systems
2 - Marketing
3 - Sports
I can make a backend validation where the Id passed cant be > to the max value of the id in the table (with a lambda expresion).

What I cant control (I think) if they Swap values:
2 - Systems
3 - Marketing
1 - Sports

It will save an 'alumno' with the incorrect value (Well, now that I think of it, if they want to mix values, then they want to create it without using a GUI :P

Comment: Well, if they send a value that's out of range, I suspect that *should* result in an error even just based on a foreign key constraint in the data, no?  If not, then sure, you can manually validate the range exactly as you describe.  And if they swap values but are still in the range, then that's not really a problem either.  So the user saw the text "Systems" but posted the value for "Sports"?  Well, the user did this *explicitly*.  The user *knows* they submitted the value for "Sports".  So, as far as the code is concerned, the user selected "Sports".  That's still a valid value to select.

Answer (score 0):

As a general protection guidelines you should ALWAYS validate as much as you can any data that is coming from the user. Think of it as if it would be tainted with digital Antrax or something. So yes, validate it but don't refrain from sending the ID to the front.

Also, if you're concerned about changing the order then I have to believe the order of Turnos is important. If so then ID should not be the one providing order, it's job is to provide IDentification so: How about marking it with another field for order? Maybe the start time for the Turno?

Comment: That is a good idea, because if someone decides to delete a turno (for example 2) the next most close date would be the 3.